# Facing issue with generate image using Highcharts Node.js Module

Tags: node.js, highcharts

I have created the project `Node Js Console Application` in Visual Studio 2019. Added `Node V12.16.3` and `npm v6.14.5`.

I have added node js export server package with accept license terms as below.

[image]

Server package version details

[image]

`Package.Json` Code

```
{
    "name": "prj.services.export.high-chart-export-engine",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "prj.Services.Export.HighChartExportEngine",
    "main": "app.js",  
    "author": {
        "name": ""
    },
    "dependencies": {
         "highcharts-export-server": "^2.0.28"
    }
}
```

Below is my `app.js` Code

```
var exportSettings = {
type: 'png',    
options: {
    title: {
        text: 'My Chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mar", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    },
    series: [
        {
            type: 'line',
            data: [1, 3, 2, 4]
        },
        {
            type: 'line',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 2]
        }
    ]
  }
};

//Set up a pool of PhantomJS workers
exporter.initPool();

//Perform an export
/*
Export settings corresponds to the available CLI arguments described
above.
*/
exporter.export(exportSettings, function (err, res) {
//The export result is now in res.
//If the output is not PDF or SVG, it will be base64 encoded (res.data).
//If the output is a PDF or SVG, it will contain a filename (res.filename).

//Kill the pool when we're done with it, and exit the application
exporter.killPool();
process.exit(1);
});
```

It is returning the base64 and if I convert it to base64 to image than its creating blank image with 2KB size.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same configuration as you and with the generated `base64` string I'm able to display a correct image. Take a look at the example below. Be sure to correctly use the string, don't forget to add the required information (e.g. `data:image/png;base64`) before the actual string. Btw. if you are using Highcharts version v7.0.0 and above, you don't need to fetch scripts for style mode (more info here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css).

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u4sro916/

**[UPDATE]**

The asynchronous version of the writeFileSync is simply the writeFile. I have used the function to save a file as a PNG and it works as expected. Here is the updated code of the export's callback:

```
exporter.export(exportSettings, function (err, res) {
    // The export result is now in res.
    // If the output is not PDF or SVG, it will be base64 encoded (res.data).
    // If the output is a PDF or SVG, it will contain a filename (res.filename).

    // Kill the pool when we're done with it, and exit the application
    exporter.killPool();

    fs.writeFile('image.png', res.data, 'base64', function(err) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('File successfully created!');
        }
        process.exit(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: I am using fs.writefileasync for genrate image from base64 but its retuning the blank image. Same command i follow on machine so facing that issue.

Comment: And one more thing i don't have rights to download package from server so how can i deploy the code. Do i need to copy an paste the node_module from working solutions.

Comment: @Manish Ok, so could you provide me with the rest of the code (the chartExporterEngine.js file I guess) that you use after acquiring the base64 string? Thanks.

Comment: @ManishSharma I have updated my answer. Please check it for more info.

Comment: I have used same approach but same code is working on other machine but not working on mine.

Comment: @ManishSharma It is hard to indicate what is the reason behind it based only on provided information. What are the OS of both machines? What is the content of the res.data when you run the script on a machine where it fails to generate a PNG? Are you sure that the export server is configured correctly and all requirements are met on both machines? Do you receive errors (try to log both err arguments from the export function and from the writeFile's callback). Also, try to place the exporter.logLevel(4); before initiating the phantom pool to see if export server works correctly.

Comment: @pawek_d How can I deploy code on an offline server. We don't have internet access on the server.